# Combustion Theory Book Recommendation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, partial-derivative, mathematical-modeling, heat-equation

I am conducting research on highly volatile chemicals and have been recommended to read **Mathematical Problems 
from CombustionTheory**. I was wondering whether there is another book that could be recommend which isn’t as proof heavy?

For example a book which is aimed more at engineering’s would be good to see where the various theorems and corollaries are used.